# How to use shell echo command to append a file inside a GNU Makefile target

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, echo

I am trying to append some text to a file from inside a make target using the following syntax

```
$shell(echo "module load ABC/$$(MODULE_LOAD)" >> $@/_env/local/filexyz)
```

but GNU Make 4.2.1 is complaining with the following.

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token echo
```

In summary I want the file PQR/_env/local/filexyz to have the following text on the last line

```
module load ABC/4.5.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, that's the wrong syntax for a make function; it should be `$(shell ...)` not `$shell(...)`.

Second, I assume this actually is appearing inside a recipe since you're using `$@`.  When asking questions please include enough details so that we can see the entire context, such as the entire recipe not just a single line.

It's a serious anti-pattern to use the `shell` function when you're writing a recipe, because each line in the recipe is *already* run by a shell.  It's just confusing and can cause many problems to use the `shell` function.

Third, you don't want to escape the variable `$$(MODULE_LOAD)` since that will cause the shell to run a command `MODULE_LOAD` which likely doesn't exist.

Just write it directly:

```
    echo "module load ABC/$(MODULE_LOAD)" >> $@/_env/local/filexyz
```